# Robolectric/Mockito gives error 'when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock' but it is a Mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Actually the problem is stranger than the title. I have two tests, and I cannot see the difference between them. In one I do

```
when(context.getPackageManager()).thenReturn(packageManager);
```

and it works fine. I do the same thing in another, and I get the error.

Here is the test that succeeds:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public class BtScannerMockTests
{
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.LENIENT);

```
@Mock
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
@Mock
BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
@Mock
PackageManager packageManager;
@Mock
Context context;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
}

private void setUpMocksForAdapter()
{
    BtScanner.testBtleSupport = true;
    AndroidBtManager.setBluetoothAdpater(bluetoothAdapter);
    when(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
    when(bluetoothAdapter.getState()).thenReturn(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON);
    when(bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()).thenReturn(bluetoothLeScanner);
    when(context.getPackageManager()).thenReturn(packageManager);
    when(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)).thenReturn(true);
}

private long startTime = 0;
private long time = 0;
private ScannerCountDownLatch countDownLatch;
private int btDiscoveryTime;
private int btleScanTime;

@Test
public void testBtScannerCycle_BtleScanlength() throws InterruptedException
{
    StatusEventCallback statusEventCallback = new StatusEventCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStatusEvent(StatusEvent statusEvent, PhdInformation phdInformation)
        {
            System.out.println("Status event " + statusEvent.name());
            switch(statusEvent)
            {
                case BTLE_SCAN_STARTED:
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case CLASSIC_SCAN_STARTED:
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime - btleScanTime;
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    btDiscoveryTime = 1000;
    btleScanTime = 10000;
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    setUpMocksForAdapter();
    AndroidBtManager.setStatusEventCallback(statusEventCallback);
    BtScanner.setScanTimes(btDiscoveryTime, btleScanTime);
    BtScanner btScanner = new BtScanner(context, bluetoothAdapter);
    startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
    countDownLatch = new ScannerCountDownLatch(2);
    btScanner.start();
    shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle();
    if(countDownLatch.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) // Assert length of btle scan time 1
    {
        assertTrue((time > -50 && time < 50));
        countDownLatch = new ScannerCountDownLatch(1);
        if(countDownLatch.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS))  // Assert length of btle scan time 2
        {
            assertTrue((time > -50 && time < 50));
        }
        else // Timeout
        {
            fail();
        }
    }
    else  // Timeout
    {
        fail();
    }
    btScanner.terminateScan();
    assertFalse(btScanner.isBtScannerRunning());
}
```

The test is a little complex but the line of importance is in the 'setUpMocksForAdapter()'. It works fine. 
The test that fails is simpler because it is not finished and it has no assertions yet.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public class ProprietaryDriverMonitorTests
{
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.LENIENT);
@Mock
Intent intent;
@Mock
ResolveInfo resolveInfo1;
@Mock
ResolveInfo resolveInfo2;
@Mock
PackageManager packageManager;
@Mock
Context context;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
    context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    ContinuaHandlerThread.isUnitTesting = true;
}

private List<ResolveInfo> matches = new ArrayList<>();

@Test
public void testBasicCycle() throws Exception
{
    setUp();
    matches.clear();
    matches.add(resolveInfo1);
    matches.add(resolveInfo2);
    when(context.getPackageManager()).thenReturn(packageManager);
    when(packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0)).thenReturn(matches);
    //resolveInfo1.serviceInfo.packageName
    AndroidBtManager androidBtManager = new AndroidBtManager(context, false, false, true);
    ProprietaryDriverMonitor proprietaryDriverMonitor =
            new ProprietaryDriverMonitor(androidBtManager, context, 5);
    proprietaryDriverMonitor.start();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
}
```

This test gives the failure when I do 'when(context.getPackageManager()).thenReturn(packageManager);' I cannot see why this test fails and the other test does not. What am I doing wrong in test 2 that I am somehow doing right in test 1?

Comment: Why call a "setUp" method from the test method? It is already called on @Before annotation. Also, try to use ShadowPackageManager.class on Robolectric lib.

Comment: I had trouble figuring out how to use the ShadowPackageManger; it seemed to have real issues with the Bluetooth APIs. But otherwise I would love to.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Mocks with Robolectric are not popular topics. In any case the answer turns out to be that the mock (in this case the Context) was overridden by another call that generated the context. The initial Mock of that context survives until that call that overrides it. In one test the overriding call was done before a given check and in the other case, after.

Its hard to see in the complicated unit tests but it is difficult to write simple unit tests that when Bluetooth Connections are involved. I have found it impossible to test certain features because Android or the library overrides any Mock that I need to perform during the tested procedure.